# Как сравнить основной массив со вторым?

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброе утро! Подскажите пожалуйста. Как сравнить один основной массив со вторым на соответствия названия? И после это название вывести?

```
function mainA() {
$mycontent = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'size',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(10),
        )
    ),
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
$mycontent = $mycontent->get_posts();

foreach ($mycontent as $post) {
    $str3 = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $post->post_title);
    print_r($str3);}}
```

Тут я беру тайтлы постов и вывожу только числа (которые являются артикулом для сравнения)

```
function b() {
$html = file_get_html('https://tagtekstil.com.ua/postelnoe-tm-tag/polutornyi/policotton1-5');

foreach($html->find('.spacer h2 a') as $element)  {
    // echo $element->innertext;
    $str2 = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $element->innertext);
    print_r($str2);
};}
```

Тут я с сайта подтягиваю так же названия постов и выделяю только цифры .

Задача получить название тех постов, которых нет у меня . и Вывести их .

Спасибо

Comment: переформулируйте вопрос, приведите примеры двух массивов для сравнения

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php